# How do I implement HTML table sorting when table is populated via Struts

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, struts2, html-table

I have a HTML table in which the elements are populated via struts (the `<s:iterator>` tag). The code snippet is shown below.

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="select_table margin-top10" id="example_table">
        <thead>
            <tr class="oddRows">
                <th width="300px" align="left">Column A</th>
                <th width="150px" align="left">Column B</th>
                <th width="120px"align="left">Column C</th>
                <th align="left">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
<div style="height:200px;" class="data_holder">
    <table class="select_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 670px;">
        <tbody>
        <s:iterator value="exampleList" status="searchResultStatus">
            <tr id="exampleRow-<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>" <s:if test="#searchResultStatus.even">class="oddRows"</s:if> >
                <td id="sName<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>" width="295px"><span id="scheduleName<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>" class="ellipsis35" title="<s:property value="exampleName"/>"><s:property value="exampleName"/></span></td>
                <td id="sType<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>" width="150px"><span id="sType<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>"><s:property  value="exampleType" /></span></td>
                <td id="sLevel<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>"><span id="sLevel<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>"><s:property  value="exampleLevel" /></span></td>
                <td width="10%"><div title="Click to select" id="select-contact-<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>" ><img  id="select-contact-<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>" src="../images/popup-select.gif"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

How do I implement sorting on this table? Please help!

Comment: You can use jQuery datagrid with Struts2 JSON plugin, for example see http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html
Or Use library like 
[jmesa] : https://code.google.com/p/jmesa/ Or
[displaytag] : http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/

Comment: I want to use HTML tables itself. The same format as given above. Though display tag is an option, I wouldn't want to use it.

Comment: In the code above you are even didn't try to write a code. For better help sooner, post the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using struts2 [s:sort](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/sort.html) tag.

```
<s:sort comparator="your.impl.of.comparator" source="exampleList">
    <s:iterator status="searchResultStatus">
        <tr id="exampleRow-<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>" <s:if test="#searchResultStatus.even">class="oddRows"</s:if> >
            <td id="sName<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>" width="295px"><span id="scheduleName<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>" class="ellipsis35" title="<s:property value="exampleName"/>"><s:property value="exampleName"/></span></td>
            <td id="sType<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>" width="150px"><span id="sType<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>"><s:property  value="exampleType" /></span></td>
            <td id="sLevel<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>"><span id="sLevel<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>"><s:property  value="exampleLevel" /></span></td>
            <td width="10%"><div title="Click to select" id="select-contact-<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>" ><img  id="select-contact-<s:property value="#searchResultStatus.index"/>" src="../images/popup-select.gif"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</s:sort>
```

Where *your.impl.of.comparator* is an implementation of *java.util.Comparator*